# How to pull specific object from json api call in php

Tags: php, arrays, json, api, foreach

I am trying to pull a specific object from the API call output in json.

```
{"result":[{"created_at":1567946574,"id":123456,"ip":"10.0.0.1/32","updated_at":1567946574},{"created_at":1588953004,"id":123457,"ip":"10.0.0.2/32","updated_at":1588953004},{"created_at":1588953021,"id":123458,"ip":"10.0.0.3/32","updated_at":1588953021},{"created_at":1588953090,"id":123459,"ip":"10.0.0.4/32","updated_at":1588953090},{"created_at":1588953090,"id":123460,"ip":"10.0.0.5/32","updated_at":1588953090}]}
```

I want to pull the value of id based on IP value.

Say i have IP 10.0.0.4, i want its id using php.

I have set up a code to just pull ID as of now, but it doesn't work. Can anyone help me?

```
$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

$characters = json_decode($response); // decode the JSON feed

foreach ( $characters as $output ) {   
        echo $output->id;
    }
```

Comment: `json_decode()` returns an object rather than array, unless you give it the second argument `true`.

Comment: Also, the array is in the `result` property.

Comment: You need `$characters->result`, not `$characters`. https://3v4l.org/immdI

Comment: tried that as well, still white screen. However if i remove {"result": and } from the bottom, it works, idk why.